# ASP .NET MVC Reports

Tags: model-view-controller, report, dashboard

As you can see i'm a newbie at this site and have a question about asp.net mvc and reporting. I want to create reports (interactive - for example when the data is displayed you can filter some information by categories or countries witout generating the report again) and dashboards for a mvc project and I don't know which tool to use. Has anybody used any tool that works for mvc and has options like this. I have worked before with crystal reports but only static reports for printing.

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0):

SSRS will help you get started, It can be used with MVC as well.

[MSDN MVC & SSRS Part 1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sajoshi/archive/2010/06/16/asp-net-mvc-handling-ssrs-reports-with-reportviewer-part-i.aspx)

[MSDN MVC & SSRS Part 2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sajoshi/archive/2010/06/16/asp-net-mvc-handling-ssrs-reports-with-reportviewer-part-ii-deployment-challenges.aspx)

[Article By John V. Petersen](http://www.codemag.com/article/1009061)

Answer (score 0):

I think this can help you, in the scenario you described I would do something like this ...

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/616156/Simple-Dashboard

Keep in mind: Always try program data and behaviors in your applications...